# PHP MVC & .htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am restructuring a website to a MVC framework and am in the process of moving everything from root the root directory into an organized file structure.  So now instead of going to domian.org/homeloans.php, the users will need to do domain.org/loans/homeloans.  Here is the .htaccess file I use to direct website traffic.

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectorySlash on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Shouldn't this  be as simple as adding:

```
Redirect 301 /homeloans.php https://domain.org/loans/homeloans
```

after turning the rewrite engine on?  However, when I do this, I get this in my address bar along with a 404:  https://domain.org/loans/homeloans?rt=homeloans.php

Please advise.

Comment: Well that makes sense... you are setting `?rt` to the value of the capture group which would be `homeloans.php`. Your rewrite should be to `index.php` and then you workout what resources to access on the PHP side.

Comment: In your code above you've misspelt Redirect as "Recirect". Does this typo appear in your .htaccess file, or just here on this page?

Comment: @Arkanon Fixed it, the problem was just on this page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be not with the rewrite, but with the ability of your new MVC site to handle this URL. It looks like it can handle:

```
/loans/homeloans
```

but not

```
/loans/homeloans?rt=homeloans.php
```

Try accessing both directly; if the latter doesn't work but the former doesn't, then you know the issue is with the routing configuration of your MVC application.

Comment: ?rt tells the Router what controller and action to call, so it should be calling the Loan Conrtoller with and the homeloans method.  /loans/homeloans?rt=loans/homeloans works though

Comment: In that case, it's because of the .php on the end I suspect - the request is being processed by PHP instead of your MVC application. Web server configuration...